# iOS-How to display Gold color

Tags: ios, colors

I'm trying to set the background color of my view to gold. I've found RGB values for several tones of this value. For this I simply do this:

```
[myView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:252.0 green:194.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
```

But i just get the same color as for the yellow. The same is true for silver color. I get the same color as for white. Is there a way to achieve this or iOS does not support this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

color values are between 0 to 1.0f

```
myView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 
                                 green:194.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: In hex, this is FCC200

Comment: This answer works! Here it is in Swift: let gold = UIColor(red: 252.0/255.0, green: 194.0/255.0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)

Answer (score 6):

`UIColor` takes color percentages, from 0-1, instead of 0-255. Divide those RGB values by 255.0 to get the desired color.

[UIColor Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a)

Comment: Hmmmm, I'd totally forgotten about this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 11 Swift 5**

you can work with color literals !

```
var gold = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9882352941, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

It renders like this ...

[image: gold image]

Answer (score 1):

Metallic appearance cannot be accurately expressed by a solid color because part of what gives metal it's characteristic look is it's [sheen](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sheen).  The same is true of fluorescence.  If you're attempting to simulate a metallic surface then you need to simulate metallic sheen.

Answer (score 0):

Gold is not a RGB color, gold is reflective, this means it reflects the color of everything else but with a warm yellow coloring.

Check this out for a good gold gradient: [Gold gradient on deviant art](http://ademmm.deviantart.com/art/gold-gradient-88530918)